# Regex parse string in java

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java. I need to parse the following line using regex :

```
<actions>::=<action><action>|X|<game>|alpha
```

It should give me tokens `<action>`, `<action>`,`X` and `<game>`

What kind of regex will work?

I was trying sth like: `"<[a-zA-Z]>"` but that doesn't take care of `X` or `alpha`.

Comment: Should it match `alpha` or not?

Comment: yes it should also include alpha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
String str="<actions>::=<action><action>|X|<game>|alpha";
str=str.split("=")[1];
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<.*?>|\\|.*?\\|");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: this includes X with |X|. regex should ignore |

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this:

```
String input = "<actions>::=<action><action>|X|<game>|alpha";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(<[^>]+>)(<[^>]+>)\\|([^|]+)\\|(<[^|]+>)").matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(matcher.group().replaceAll("\\|", ""));
}
```

You didn't specefied if you want to return *alpha* or not, in this case, it doesn't return it.

You can return alpha by adding `|\\w*` to the end of the regex I wrote.

This will return:

```
<action><action>X<game>
```

Comment: pattern should not include the "|". this spits out:token:<action>
token:<action>
token:<action>
token:|X|
token:<game>

Comment: Can you also tell me how to tokenize this:<actions>::=<action><action><action>action. Here there are no "|" and you need to get tokens <action>,<action>,<action> and action? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the original pattern it is not clear if you mean that literally there are <> in the pattern or not, i'll go with that assumption.

```
String pattern="<actions>::=<(.*?)><(.+?)>\|(.+)\|<(.*?)\|alpha";
```

For the java code you can use Pattern and Matcher: here is the basic idea:

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL|Pattern.MULTILINE);
   Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
   m.find();
   for (int g = 1; g <= m.groupCount(); g++) {
      // use your four groups here..
   }
```

Comment: wait, why is alpha hardcoded here. Yes it should include "<" and ">" and also words that do not contain these "<" and ">" endings. In the example above, tokens should be <action>, <action>,X,<game>,alpha.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following Java regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile
       ("::=(<[^>]+>)(<[^>]+>)\\|([^|]+)\\|(<[^>]+>)\\|(\\w+)$");
```

Comment: @Dev: Or see the Java code with above regex running here: http://ideone.com/8b7DP0